# Rails, fields_for generate fields for as many attachments (even 0), while I want only/at least one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have **areas** and every area has multiple images through **area_attachments**.

I have a modal to **edit** each area.

I also want to edit **area_attachments** in each **area** so I have a **f.fields_for** in every area form.

```
<%first_rendered=false %>
<%= f.fields_for :area_attachments do |aa| %>
  <%unless first_rendered %>
  <div class="field">
   <br>
   <%= aa.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "area_attachments[image][]" %>
  </div>
  <% first_rendered=true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Because it is multiple upload I only want one field so the user can upload more images to an **area**.

As you can see I have a **first_rendered** variable, so if an **area** has more than one **area_attachments** the field will only show once, there is no reason for more fields.

But if an **area** has no **area_attachments** at all, the field will not show up at all.

What would you suggest I do here? Also, would you do something else instead of this **first_rendered** variable I used?
Generally, how would you do it so only one field is generated?

Comment: So this isn't really an edit form (at least this part of it) - it's a new attachment form. Correct?

Comment: @FrederickCheung Now that you say it.. yes, it's a field to upload more images. I have added another way to delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, instead of using the code in my question, I used the following.

```
<%= f.fields_for :area_attachments, @area.area_attachments.build do |aa| %>              
  <div class="field">
   <br>
   <%= aa.file_field :image, :multiple => true, name: "area_attachments[image][]" %>
  </div>                          
<% end %>
```

And it worked fine.
The **first_render** stuff wasn't even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the default behaviour of iterating through the collection, then don't use `fields_for`.

If you name the input `area_attachment_attributes[1][image][]` then it should still use `accepts_nested_attributes` to build new `AreaAttachment` objects as desired. The `1` in the input name is not important in your case, since you only want to allow construction of one object, but otherwise it would be used to separate out the parameters to use for each object to build.

Comment: I found around in stack overflow something like this:

`<%= f.fields_for :comments, @product.comments.build do |comment| %>`
Do you think it would work in my case?

Comment: In this form:
`<%= f.fields_for :area_attachments, @area.area_attachments.build do |aa| %>`

Comment: I solved it that way. Thanks anyway for trying to help.